# R-Shiny: Nas introduced by coercion

Tags: r, shiny

I'm just starting with Shiny.

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to launch my code:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3626 Warning in cc(input$Atacante,
>   input$Tirada_At, input$Defensor, input$Tirada_Def) :   NAs introduced
>   by coercion Warning in cc(input$Atacante, input$Tirada_At,
>   input$Defensor, input$Tirada_Def) :   NAs introduced by coercion

The problem is regarding the non-numeric parameters demanded by the function. The inputs from selectImput with id "Atacante" and "Defensor" are not well processed in my function. I've been trying several changes but is not working. If someone could help me I would be really grateful. (I apologize for the freaky terms)

Here's the server:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {

   damage <- reactive({

    Mob1<- c(40,40,45)
    Mob2<- c(10,10,10)

    cc <- function(Atacante,Tirada_At,Defensor,Tirada_Def){

      Valores_at<-as.numeric(Atacante[1:3])
      Ataque_final<-Valores_at[1]+Tirada_At

      Valores_def<-as.numeric(Defensor[1:3])
      Defensa_final<-Valores_def[2]+Tirada_Def

      res_sin_abs<- (Ataque_final - Defensa_final)
    }

    cc(input$Atacante,input$Tirada_At,input$Defensor,input$Tirada_Def)

  })

  output$dam <- renderTable({
    damage()
  })

}
```

and here's the UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Combate"),

  sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

  sliderInput("Tirada_At", "Tirada atacante:",
              min = -100, max = 200,
              value = 50),


  sliderInput("Tirada_Def", "Tirada Defensor:",
              min = -100, max = 200,
              value = 50),

  selectInput(inputId= "Atacante", label="Atacante:",choices = c("Mob1","Mob2")),
  selectInput(inputId="Defensor", label="Defensor:", choices = c("Mob1","Mob2"))
),

mainPanel(

  tableOutput("dam")

)
  )
)
```

Comment: is your function working outside shiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can put `browser()` inside reactive expressions and observers to debug your shiny apps like this

```
 damage <- reactive({

    Mob1<- c(40,40,45)
    Mob2<- c(10,10,10)

    cc <- function(Atacante,Tirada_At,Defensor,Tirada_Def){
      browser()
      Valores_at<-as.numeric(Atacante[1:3])
      Ataque_final<-Valores_at[1]+Tirada_At

      Valores_def<-as.numeric(Defensor[1:3])
      Defensa_final<-Valores_def[2]+Tirada_Def

      res_sin_abs<- (Ataque_final - Defensa_final)
    }

    cc(input$Atacante,input$Tirada_At,input$Defensor,input$Tirada_Def)

  })
```

Running the app now will give you the option to explore the current value of the inputs like this.

```
## Called from: cc(input$Atacante, input$Tirada_At, input$Defensor, input$Tirada_Def)
Browse[1]> Valores_at<-as.numeric(Atacante[1:3])
## Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
Browse[1]> Atacante[1:3]
## [1] "Mob1" NA     NA    
Browse[1]> Atacante
## [1] "Mob1"
Browse[1]> get(Atacante)
## [1] 40 40 45
```

So as you can see, `Atacante` is a character vector of length one holding the selection from the UI. If you want to aquire the vercor defined before with `Mob1 <- ...`, you can use `get`.

I personally don't like using `get` in my projects so here how I would code this

```
damage <- reactive({

  mobs <- data.frame(
    Mob1 = c(40, 40, 45),
    Mob2 = c(10, 10, 10)
  )

  cc <- function(Atacante, Tirada_At, Defensor, Tirada_Def){
    Valores_at <- mobs[[Atacante]]
    Ataque_final <- Valores_at[1] + Tirada_At

    Valores_def <- mobs[[Defensor]]
    Defensa_final <- Valores_def[2] + Tirada_Def

    res_sin_abs <- (Ataque_final - Defensa_final)
  }

  cc(input$Atacante, input$Tirada_At, input$Defensor, input$Tirada_Def)

})
```